# How to use a calculated name in a formula

Tags: excel

Is it possible to calculate a name to be used in a formula?

say I have this formula:

```
MATCH(C12;_PR.item;0)
```

I would like to compute the name from a string and a cell like the following that doesn't work

```
MATCH(C12;"_PR."&C1;0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT`:

```
=MATCH(C12;INDIRECT("_PR."&C1);0)
```

It takes a text string and converts it to a reference.

Comment: +1; but us sparingly. It makes maintaining spreadsheets difficult; your spreadsheet may break if you insert or delete rows or columns.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yup. `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and can break things if one is not careful.